# VoIP using audioqueues and the iLBC codec. Choppy sound

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio, voip

i develop a voip app for MacOSX. I have managed to record iLBC audio (1 channel, 8KHz samplerate, 160 frames per packet, 38 bytes pers packet). As fas as know iLBC records Constant Bit Rate Compressed audio and i create buffers of size 950 bytes for 0.5 seconds duration. I do this by using AudioQueues (inside the AudioInputCallback function).

Next, i transform the mAudioData to NSData object and i send the objects to the remote app, using UDP packets and GCDAsyncUDPSocket.

I manage to get the remote objects. I create an AudioQueueOutput and inside the callback i fill the buffers. However sound comes out very choppy. And i am stack....

One think i noticed is that if i ask from Core Audio and the output queue to fill the AudioBasicDescriptionFormat for iLBC, it gives me a different format than the one used for recording.

Has anyone experience with this case?

I don't audiofilestream at all. I read in another question in this forum, that VoIP can be done by just using AudioQueues only.

Thanks very much for reading my question!!!

Comment: have you found a solution, yet?